# IndexError: list index out of range for multi level columns dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataset with the following characteristics. 3 indexes. 2 layers of column levels.
For each index there are 2 rows of data.

With that being said, I'm trying to filter for rows with values on one column greater than 0.7 but I only receive Index Error.

My dataframe is as follows

```
indx=['nmatch','pts','gfa','gco','cs','fts','bts','o25%','po25/bts']
findx=[('fecha',''),('torneo',''),('partido','')]+[('h/a stats',x) for x in indx]+[('total stats',y) for y in indx]
index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(findx, names=['tipo', 'stat'])

fframe=pd.DataFrame(l,columns=index)
fframe.set_index(['fecha','torneo','partido'],inplace=True)
```

If I do

```
fframe[fframe[('h/a stats','po25/bts')]>0.7]
```

I get something like

```
date    trophy        match         data
 A        B        ganma v theta     True
 A        B        ganma v theta     False
 F        B        Etha v psi        True
 F        B        Etha v psi        True
 C        D        epsilon v mu      False
 C        D        epsilon v mu      False
```

and if I do

```
ind=fframe.index[f[('h/a stats','po25/bts')]>0.7]
```

I get the indexes for it, but when I do

```
fframe.loc[ind]

>IndexError: list index out of range
```

I would like for the indexes to be unique, instead of 4 B there should be only one B, and instead of 2 matches there only should be one there.
But mostly, what I want is to get a frame with all True rows, and if happens a case like for ganma v theta where one row is True and the other False, to show both of them

Comment: should it be fframe.loc[ind]

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misspelled it there. Still on my console it was correct and the output is the one I wrote